# Big Sur TextEdit delete line jumps to start of plain text file

Tags: textedit, macos-big-sur

When I delete a line in a plain text file in `TextEdit` on `Big Sur` (only), the cursor stays in the correct position, but the window scrolls up to the start of the file.  I would expect no scrolling to occur.

To reproduce:

- create a new file and convert it to plain text
- make it 50 lines long. It can have any content, e.g. 1 character per line
- reduce the height of the window to 20 lines, to ensure scrolling can be observed
- scroll to end of file
- use backspace to delete a line or 2 from near the end of the file.

Observed result: window scrolls to the top of the file

Expected result: no scrolling

Is there any workaround, or a setting that can be changed so that this behaviour is not observed?

Comment: The obvious workaround is to change files to RTF format.  It's not obvious to me how to file a bug report with Apple, but I've reported this issue using the feedback assistant https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/8902964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be fixed in macOS 11.1 (20C69), released on December 14, 2020.

Comment: Yes, I can no longer reproduce.  Thank you for pointing it out, I might not have noticed for a while!